# Visual Studio 2015 remove keyboard shortcut

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Sometime within the past week my F2 keyboard shortcut in Visual Studio 2015 stopped triggering Refactor->Rename. So I went into keyboard mappings and re-linked it, but it still doesn't work. I see there are many other functions mapped to F2 but I can't see any way to delete/remove those other mapping. I know I have done this before in previous versions of VS but there doesn't seem to be any way to do it now.

How is it done?

Comment: do you have any third party extensions like Resharper or CodeRush?

Comment: Can you reset to (Default) mapping scheme or would that mess up other hotkeys?

Comment: I do have resharper but it's disabled in my VS2015. And I've had resharper installed for a long time, but only in the last few days did this keyboard shortcut get messed up.